# Drop down adaptive card with Choice of inputs based on previous drop down selection

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

Is there an adaptive card that is available If my Answer is selected as "1" then show the next drop downs as "A",if the answer is selected "2" then show B ,So basically changes the drop down output depending on the answer that is selected.

did not get any info on this

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do this. [ShowCard](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.ShowCard.html) allows you to expand or show an additional card, but I don't think you can get it to dynamically create the child card. If you are using a Bot channel (MS Teams, Slack, Telegram) that [supports message update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channels-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#activity-support-by-channel), then you could then just post some value from the original card to the bot and have it update/replace the existing card.

Comment: I have embedded the code to a test website and then tried it.Am not sure if the card can manage dynamic changes ,